# Sort an object according to an array with underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to sort an object comparing with an array. So the loop will look for specific values on the array, until it finds one, and put those 3 elements at the beginning and the rest at the end.
I am unsure what is the best way to do this any ideas?

It is something like that:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 2,4,5,6, 2]; 
var arrSimilar = [1,2,5]


var testSortBy = _.sortBy(arr, function(arrSimilar){    
  // [1,2,5,3,4,6,2]   
});

console.log(testSortBy); // [1,2,5,3,4,6,2]
```

Comment: Where are two `2`s included as elements at resulting array?

Comment: yes they can be repited

Comment: Why are there not two `5`s at expected result?

Comment: Somebody change my question... there are suppose to be two 2

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and take the index of the value of `similar` array as `priority` sorting and then take the index of all other values as order.

Important is to delete a used value of the `similar` array, because it is now in use and has no meaning for further similar values. That means, same values are sorted to their original relative index.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2],
    similar = [1, 2, 5],
    result = array
        .map(function (a, i) {
            var priority = similar.indexOf(a);
            delete similar[priority]; // delete value, but keep the index of other items
            return { index: i, priority: (priority + 1) || Infinity };
        })
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.priority - b.priority || a.index - b.index;
        })
        .map(function (o) {
            return array[o.index];
        });

console.log(result); // [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 2]
```

Comment: interesting I am going to try

Comment: this makes more sense than anything I will try!... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following way

1. Suppose A[] is the original array and B is the priority Array
2. The answer would be (B intersection A) concat (A-B)

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 2,4,5,6]; 
var arrSimilar = [1,2,5];

let bInterA = arrSimilar.filter((e) => arr.indexOf(e) != -1);

let aDiffb = arr.filter((e) => arrSimilar.indexOf(e) == -1);

console.log(bInterA.concat(aDiffb));
```